# How to figure out the physical machines on which the build tasks were run with Azure DevOps REST Api?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We have an on-premise Azure DevOps 2019. I need to know what builds run on what machines, not agents.

**Motivation:** When the builds are slow I would like to know what builds are running on a particular physical machine (which could be a virtual machine, but for this purpose I call them physical to distinguish from the agents). This could help us figure out if some builds should not be running on the same machines.

Given a build object, I can extract the worker name from the build tasks:

```
C:\> (Invoke-RestMethod $Build._links.timeline.href -UseDefaultCredentials).records.workerName |? { $_ } | sort -unique
TDC5DFC1BLD10_02
C:\>
```

So, I know all the tasks in the build were run on the build agent TDC5DFC1BLD10_02. But I want to know the physical machine name. So, I query the agent using its name:

```
C:\> (Invoke-RestMethod "$TfsInstanceUrl/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$($build.queue.pool.id)/agents?agentName=TDC5DFC1BLD10_02" -UseDefaultCredentials).value


_links            : @{self=; web=}
maxParallelism    : 1
createdOn         : 2019-05-16T19:33:31.567Z
authorization     : @{clientId=c4cebb22-e14f-4fdb-844c-079150766efc; publicKey=}
id                : 308
name              : TDC5DFC1BLD10_02
version           : 2.131.0
osDescription     : Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393
enabled           : True
status            : online
provisioningState : Provisioned



C:\>
```

But it does not give me the physical machine. I have no idea what queue or pool is, but I can check them too:

```
C:\> $Build.queue | ConvertTo-Json
{
    "id":  1929,
    "name":  "GC-Master-TDC5DFC1BLD08-11",
    "pool":  {
                 "id":  90,
                 "name":  "GC-Master-TDC5DFC1BLD08-11"
             }
}
C:\> Invoke-RestMethod "$TfsInstanceUrl/SharpTop/_apis/distributedtask/queues/1929" -UseDefaultCredentials | ConvertTo-Json
{
    "id":  1929,
    "projectId":  "ecff38d6-a219-4739-8b97-5e5d8d00e7ed",
    "name":  "GC-Master-TDC5DFC1BLD08-11",
    "pool":  {
                 "id":  90,
                 "scope":  "a984b12d-89d2-47d6-998e-b9bfaa69ee85",
                 "name":  "GC-Master-TDC5DFC1BLD08-11",
                 "isHosted":  false,
                 "poolType":  "automation",
                 "size":  8
             }
}
C:\> Invoke-RestMethod "$TfsInstanceUrl/_apis/distributedtask/pools/90" -UseDefaultCredentials


createdOn     : 2019-05-16T19:13:33.493Z
autoProvision : True
autoSize      :
agentCloudId  :
createdBy     : @{displayName=Doe, John;
                url=http://tdc1tfsapp01.xyz.com:8080/tfs/_apis/Identities/cc71b5eb-9dd6-436a-b722-6790d7ef4877; _links=;
                id=cc71b5eb-9dd6-436a-b722-6790d7ef4877; uniqueName=xyz\P120A76; imageUrl=http://tdc1tfsapp01.xyz.com:8080/t
                fs/_api/_common/identityImage?id=cc71b5eb-9dd6-436a-b722-6790d7ef4877;
                descriptor=win.Uy0xLTUtMjEtNDg3MjU1NDc3LTE2MzE1MjcwMjItMzUxNzQ0NDQyLTE1NzQy}
owner         : @{displayName=Doe, John;
                url=http://tdc1tfsapp01.xyz.com:8080/tfs/_apis/Identities/cc71b5eb-9dd6-436a-b722-6790d7ef4877; _links=;
                id=cc71b5eb-9dd6-436a-b722-6790d7ef4877; uniqueName=xyz\P120A76; imageUrl=http://tdc1tfsapp01.xyz.com:8080/t
                fs/_api/_common/identityImage?id=cc71b5eb-9dd6-436a-b722-6790d7ef4877;
                descriptor=win.Uy0xLTUtMjEtNDg3MjU1NDc3LTE2MzE1MjcwMjItMzUxNzQ0NDQyLTE1NzQy}
id            : 90
scope         : a984b12d-89d2-47d6-998e-b9bfaa69ee85
name          : GC-Master-TDC5DFC1BLD08-11
isHosted      : False
poolType      : automation
size          : 8
```

And I still have no idea of the physical machine. How do I do it?

Comment: Look at the agent's capabiltiies. There should be a computer name in there.

Comment: It is exactly so. Can you arrange it as a formal answer?

Comment: @DanielManna please add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Agent.ComputerName holds the value of hostname of the agent which executes your job.